# Uso apropiado de .htaccess

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, .htaccess, apache2

Tengo un servidor con una aplicación web desarrollada en laravel, estoy tratando de configurar el archivo .htaccess para que, si se ingresa una URL con `index.php`, este desaparezca.

Actualmente estoy usando estas líneas:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Esto hace que:

- si la URL viene como `midominio.com/index.php/home`
- se transforme en `midominio.com/home`

El problema (y consecuentemente un error) es:

- cuando viene una URL así: `midominio.com/index.php`
- transforma la url a: `midominio.com/var/www/Proyecto/public`

Si utilizo esto en el .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^index.php(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Se corrige este último error, pero no reemplaza el `index.php` de la URL. Si pongo las dos soluciones se arregla, pero me gustaría saber si es que hay una solución que junte estas dos alternativas.

**Ejemplos:**

Necesito que URL como estas

```
midominio.com/index.php/loQueSea
midominio.com/index.php
```

Se modifiquen a:

```
midominio.com/loQueSea
```

**.htaccess completo**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    #Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    #Se saca el index.php
    #RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
    RewriteRule ^(.+/)?index\.php(?:/(.*))?$ $1$2 [R=301,NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Prueba con algo como esto, quitando todo lo que tienes a ese respecto: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: Me estoy mareando un poco al leer la pregunta. ¿Podrías poner ejemplos mostrando URL inicial y a cuál se quiere redireccionar?

Comment: @Mariano editado para explicar mejor!

Comment: Está bien, el index.php debe salir de la url porque genera errores en algunas llamadas ajax @Mariano

Comment: No no debería ir a eso, ya que puede ser que las llamadas ajax vayan a midominio.com/loQueSea/llamadaAjax

Comment: @JosIgnacioArredondoRodrguez Es poco claro cómo interpretar tu ejemplo, que de `midominio.com/index.php` se redireccione a `midominio.com/loQueSea`... ¿De dónde salío `"loQueSea"` en ese caso?

Comment: @Mariano puede ser uno de los tantos módulos de mi aplicación web, por ejemplo midominio.com/administracion, midominio.com/usuarios, midominio.com/estadísticas etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No le veo el sentido a usar una `RewriteCond` en este caso.

Simplemente podemos redireccionar capturando todo lo que está antes y después de `index.php`.

```py
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+/)?index\.php(?:/(.*))?$ $1$2 [R=301,NC,L]
```

**Descripción:**

- `^` - Coincide con el inicio del texto.
- `(.+/)?` - Grupo opcional. Coincide con cualquier texto terminado en `/`. Captura en `$1`.
- `index\.php` - Literal `index.php`.
- `(?:/(.*))?` - Grupo opcional. Coincide con:

  - `/` - Literal.
  - `(.*)` - Coincide con cualquier texto. Captura en `$2`. No incluye la `/` inicial en la captura.
- `$` - Coincide con el final del texto.
- `[R=301]` - Redirección 301.
- `[NC]` - Ignorando mayúsculas/minúsculas.
- `[L]` - Si coincide, no procesar más reglas.

**Demo:**

Subí el .htaccess a un hosting gratuito para mostrar una demo en vivo:

- http://mariano.uphero.com/82546/index.php
- http://mariano.uphero.com/82546/loQueSea/index.php
- http://mariano.uphero.com/82546/index.php/loQueSea

Creé la carpeta `/82546/loQueSea`. Cualquier otra prueba va a funcionar, pero obviamente dará un error 404 porque no existe el recurso.

Comment: Gracias por la muy buena explicación, lamentablemente no me funciona, si dejo tu código, me redirige siempre a midominio.com/var/proyecto/public

Comment: @JosIgnacioArredondoRodrguez El error está en algún otro lado. Podrías probar si agregando `RewriteBase /` al inicio de tu .htaccess lo soluciona, pero no es en cuanto a esta regla. Subí una demo para que puedas probar (agregada en la respuesta).

Comment: @JosIgnacioArredondoRodrguez Otra posibilidad es que al estar probando con una redirección 301, haya quedado la redirección en caché (es por eso que nunca hay que probar con un 301 hasta estar totalmente seguro)... ¿Cómo recuperarlo? Es complicado, pero para empezar, probaría con otro navegador y en todo caso desde otra conexión.

Comment: Agregué el RewriteBase / y se queda pegado en el inicio. Editaré mi respuesta y agregaré el contenido del .htacess, será que choca con otra propiedad?

Comment: Sí, hay varios errores que no están relacionados a tu pregunta original. Te recomiendo que revises el resto de las reglas. No uses 301 hasta que te funcione!!!... Por ejemplo, no tiene sentido que elimines la / y luego realices otra redirección eliminando index.php... Además, antes de la redirección estás reescribiendo todo a index.php, no tiene sentido. Ordenalas con un sentido lógico, empezando por la redirección de esta respuesta y agregando luego el resto.

Comment: Si, es que traté de dejar la configuración según laravel y luego quise agregar otras reglas para lo que quiero, trataré de corregir los errores @Mariano